# Is is possible to get WPBakery generated rows as a variable?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, visual-composer, wpbakery

I'm creating custom elements in WPBakery (formerly Visual Composer), but encountering issues with its rendered markup.

**For example:**

I've created a custom element called `text`. `text` currently spans `12 columns` in the WP admin:

[image]

The rendered markup for this looks like:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">

  <div class="text">
    <div class="text-left container">
      <h2>This is header</h2>
      <p>This is content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

As you can see, it's creating an empty `col-sm-12` div and not even applying the column styles to `text`.

Ideally what I want to do is get the column WPBakery is generating and place it in a variable.

This way, I can do something along the lines of:

```
<div class="text <?php echo $column; ?>">
```

I think this will be handy when a user eventually decides they want two `text` blocks next to each other:

[image]

So each `text` block will be `col-6`.

To summarise, I'm trying to figure out why Bakery is outputting an empty div with `columns` rather than to wrap around my `text` block? As I'm not sure why this is happening, the only solution I can think of is to get the `column` data as a variable and then echo is in the `text` block.